# In Python, convert list to dict so that n-th element is a key

Tags: python, list, dictionary, time-complexity

**Question:** how to efficiently and pythonically convert a list of lists `my_list` to a dict `my_dict` so that zeroth element of every nested list is the key and remaining elements are a value (also list).

**Example:**

Input:

```
my_list = [['a', 'b'],
          ['b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f'],
          ['g'],
          ['h', 'i', 'j'],
          ['k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't']]
```

Output:

```
my_dict = {'a': ['b'],
          'b': ['c', 'd', 'e', 'f'],
          'g': None, 
          'h': ['i', 'j'],
          'k': ['l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't']}
```

**Side notes:**
My dataset is huge so the method needs to be clean and efficient. While iterating over the list is acceptable, I would rather avoid nesting loops (to keep O(n) complexity). I managed to write a function that gets the job done by iterating over the input list and pops the zeroth element but [popping is itself O(n)](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity) making whole solution O(n*n).

Comment: what if `mydict[i][0]` has duplicates ?

Comment: Did you mean `my_list`? In dict it if there is a key duplicate it just overwrites the old value. If you meant `my_list`, it's not expected to have duplicates, I check for it earlier in my script.

Comment: yes. I meant `my_list[i][0]` If there are no duplicates, then below answers works out without any break in data.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use a *dictionary comprehension*. The value lists or `None` are created by short-circuiting the list slice from index one with `None` using the `or` operator:

```
dct = {lst[0]: lst[1:] or None  for lst in my_list}
pprint(dct)
```

---

```
{'a': ['b'],
 'b': ['c', 'd', 'e', 'f'],
 'g': None,
 'h': ['i', 'j'],
 'k': ['l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't']}
```

---

**Complexity**:

The complexity of this dict. comp. is *O*(n*m), where *n* is the number of items in the list and *m* is the length of the largest slice. The gain here does not come in a reduction in time complexity but in CPU time.

Comment: oops, seems I am little late here, plus one for your speed :)

Comment: Or with unpacking `{a:b or None for a,*b in y_list}`

Comment: @Chris_Rands Yes, but *extended unpacking* only works in Python 3.

Comment: I should have said before - only Python 2 is considered. Thank you both for your input!

Comment: One more question - is `lst[1:]` O(n) (popping the first value) or O(1) (getting item)?

Answer (score 3):

You can use `dict comprehension` :

```
>>> { i[0]:i[1:] or None for i in my_list}
{'a': ['b'],
'b': ['c', 'd', 'e', 'f'],
'g': None,
'h': ['i', 'j'],
'k': ['l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't']}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do,

```
{ item[0]: item[1:] or None for item in my_list }
```

Answer (score 0):

This provides a O(n) solution.

```
my_list = [['a', 'b'],
      ['b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f'],
      ['g'],
      ['h', 'i', 'j'],
      ['k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't']]
print(my_list)
my_dict={}
for x in my_list:
  my_dict[x[0]]=x[1:]
print(my_dict)
```

But keep in mind that There should not be any duplicates in keys

Comment: @farincz that is my worry, too.

Comment: @farincz @Artur I presume, Slicing takes `O(end - start)`. So, the complexity depends on size of each slice. In this case, it is almost negligible for keys `a,b,g,h`. So, I have mentioned the max of `O(n) and O(end-start)`. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @voidpro according to Side notes, dataset is huge with significantly big list. We should rather call it O(N*M) if number of items and length of inner list is not dependant. Anyway it's far from linear complexity, which was subject of question.

Comment: 'Far from linear' is a well said statement regarding this problem I guess

Comment: @Artur Lets call it `O(n*k)`, as it wont confuse others. `n*n` will be like iterating a sequence of size n twice. But it is different here.

Comment: Sure, for clarity reason it will be more logical to call it O(n*k).

Answer (score 0):

List slice has O(N) complexity, same if you are using tuples. I am afraid you can't get better than O(N*N) with given input data structure.

Answer (score 0):

Using dict cmprh

```
{i[0]:i[1:] or None for i in my_list}
```

Output :

```
{'a': ['b'], 'h': ['i', 'j'], 'k': ['l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't'], 'b': ['c', 'd', 'e', 'f'], 'g': None}
```